# How to control style of GeoScaleBar?

Tags: geography, style, geodesy

I'm plotting the `GeoScaleBar` over satellite image and wish it to be white but cannot find an option which controls its styling:

```
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Yellow], FaceForm[], Entity["Ocean", "BlackSea"]["Polygon"]}, 
 GeoServer -> {StringTemplate[
    "http://khms<*Mod[#2+#3,4]*>.googleapis.com/kh?x=`2`&y=`3`&z=`1`&v=196"], 
    "ZoomRange" -> {1, 21}}, 
 GeoScaleBar -> Placed[Quantity[Range[0, 900, 100], "Kilometers"], Scaled[{.13, .25}]]]
```

> [image: GeoGraphics]

(for future: in the above `StringTemplate` the version number of Google maps `v=196` may require updating to the current version number).

How to control the styling of `GeoScaleBar`?

Comment: It's very odd isn't it?  You can say `BaseStyle -> White` and the line goes white and that's it.  You can change the `FontFamily`, the `FontSize`, even the `FontSlant`, but `FontColor` has no effect.

Answer (score 6):

Hmm, I can't find any way to give `GeoScaleBar` options, but all it does is produce some `Line` and `Text` graphics that we can alter after with some simple replacement rules:

```
    g = GeoGraphics[...];

    g /. {
      Line[x_] :> {Red, Thick, Dashed, Line[x]},
      Text[x_, y__] :> Text[Style[x, Red, 14, Bold], y]
      }
```

[image]

You can see the structure of the graphic at `g[[1,1]]`, towards the end are the `Line` and `Text` objects we're changing the formatting of.